# JS Error : jScrollPane api is undefined

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

I have a page where I need to scroll to a particular div shown inside `jscrollpane` on page load.
When I try using `scrollToElement()` provided by `jsrcollpane` it shows me this error:
`api is undefined`

```
var pane1 = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

var api = pane1.data('jsp');

api.scrollToElement("#divId", true);
```

Can somebody tell me where am I going wrong? Or is there any other file I need to include to make it work?
I have `jscrollpane` js and css included.

Thanks.